# SwiftUI Timer(fireAt: - giving Fatal error for nil value

Tags: swiftui, timer

All, I am trying to setup a timer to start at a given time and then repeat at intervals.  The Timer.init(fireAt:... initializer seems to fit this, but is giving me an "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on @main.

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

class testout {
    @objc func timerTesting() {
        print("Test")
    }
}

@main
struct My_MacOS_SandboxApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {      
        WindowGroup {                       
            TimerStartAt0Mins()         
        }
    }
}

struct TimerStartAt0Mins: View {
    
    @State private var testTimer = Timer()
    var myOut = testout()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .onAppear {
                print("now = \(Date.now.formatted())")
                let nowplus10 = Date.now.addingTimeInterval(10)
                print("now+10 = \(nowplus10.formatted())")
                myOut.timerTesting()
                testTimer = Timer.init(fireAt: nowplus10, interval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(myOut.timerTesting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }
    }
}
```

and the full error is:
My MacOS Sandbox[17252:1206390] Swift/RangeReplaceableCollection.swift:625: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I should have added that I tested for anything being nil and didn't find any of my variables being nil - those are the print lines above the Timer.init

Comment: The `Timer` initializer is wrong anyway, because you would have to add the timer to the runloop. But there are better timer APIs in SwiftUI than *objectiv-c-ish* target/action for example `TimeLineView`.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of those views... but I'm not wanting a view in this case... and even though I am not adding it to a runloop, initializing the variable should work without actually adding it in - right ?

Comment: Then use a Combine timer, or put the timer in the class, adopt `@ObservableObject` and `@Publish` when the timer fires. At least `myOut` is supposed to be a `@StateObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both of the responders - although neither was an actual solution to what I was wanting to do, they did give me inspiration on what to be researching.  It turns out, that I was using the wrong Timer.init function. I couldn't get #selector's to work in the fireAt: init - so I used the one with a block:.  I also found that the Timer is not always guaranteed to fire at the specified time (+/- a sec sometimes) so using interval: would eventually throw my needed timing off completely.

So, here is what I ended up with to get a func to run at the start (0 secs) of each minute...

```
struct TimerStartAt0Secs: View {
    
    @State private var testTimer: Timer?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onAppear {
                print("now = \(Date.now.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .complete))")
                fireAtStartOfNextMin()
            }
    }
    
    func fireAtStartOfNextMin() {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var timerStartComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .timeZone], from: Date.now)
        timerStartComponents.minute! += 1
        timerStartComponents.second = 0
        let timerStart = calendar.date(from: timerStartComponents)
        testTimer = Timer.init(fire: timerStart!, interval: 0, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            print("Test \(Date.now.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .complete))")
            fireAtStartOfNextMin()
        })
        RunLoop.main.add(testTimer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Running the above, I am finding that it is actually firing at the start of every minute (0 secs) 99+% of the time - not sure if there is a way to easily force a Timer to be exact... but for my needs, the 99+% is entirely usable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Used `Date()` instead of `Date.now` for getting the current date and time.
2. Changed the way the timer is initialized and started using the `Timer.scheduledTimer` method, which automatically adds the timer to the run loop.
3. Assigned the timer to an optional property timer to be able to handle it later and invalidated the timer when the view disappears to avoid potential memory leaks.

```
import SwiftUI

class testout {
    @objc func timerTesting() {
        print("Test")
    }
}

@main
struct My_MacOS_SandboxApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TimerStartAt0Mins()
        }
    }
}

struct TimerStartAt0Mins: View {
    var myOut = testout()
    var timer: Timer? // Declare the timer as an optional property
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onAppear {
                print("now = \(Date().formatted())") // Use Date() instead of Date.now
                let nowplus10 = Date().addingTimeInterval(10) // Use Date() instead of Date.now
                print("now+10 = \(nowplus10.formatted())")
                myOut.timerTesting()
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer( // Use scheduledTimer to automatically add the timer to the run loop
                    withTimeInterval: nowplus10.timeIntervalSinceNow,
                    repeats: true,
                    block: { _ in
                        self.myOut.timerTesting()
                    }
                )
            }
            .onDisappear {
                timer?.invalidate() // Invalidate the timer when the view disappears
            }
    }
}

extension Date {
    func formatted() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow,  Hing Tat Tsang!

Many of your answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.